# Print an array in String without using Array.toString in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to print a determined array in String form withoput using Arrays.toString function. What I have tried is the following but it turns out that method toString cannot be found and I don't know really what I am missing. I have hard times understanding the whole thinking process behind Java, so it would be great if you could explain me in detail what is happeing on each step. Thank a lot in advance!

```
class RandomIntArray { 
public static String toString(int[] a) {
       int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
       System.out.print("[" + array[0]);
       for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(", " + a[i]);
       System.out.println("]");
           }
    }
       public static void main (String[]args){
            System.out.println(toString[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You misunderstand between arrays  `array`, `a` . Also you don't call method toString, you try to access it like an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problems

- `toString[i]` is not a method call (`toString()` is), brackets `[]` are for array access
- you misunderstand between arrays `array` and `a`
- you method `toString` must return a `String` but you return nothing, and print all inside the method itself

---

#### Solution

- the initial array must be defined in the main, and passed to the method
- the method `toString` must build a `String` and return it

```
public static String toString(int[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[" + a[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        sb.append(", ").append(a[i]);
    }
    return sb.append("]").toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    System.out.println(toString(array));
}
```

---

### Improvement: handle empty array

It may be better to put all array access into the loop, because in case the array is empty, the previous code will fail at `a[0]`

```
public static String toString(int[] a) {
    String join = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    for (int val : a) {
        sb.append(join).append(val);
        join = ", ";
    }
    return sb.append("]").toString();
}
```

Example

```
System.out.println(toString(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4})); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
System.out.println(toString(new int[]{}));           // []
```

Comment: It's worth to add checks 1) for null; 2) for the length of array before including `a[0]` to print `[]` for empty array :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko I've just changed that, a second ago :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! I am so sorry for bothering you but I am really having a hard time tying to understand the thinking process of Java: I have one main question regarding your solution: what you do at the beginning with "sb" is create an array that concatenates "[" symbol and the first argument of our given array right? And the for moves along the array until the last element is reached while adding commas. Is that correct?